# How to resolve Circos SVG placing text incorrectly?

Tags: perl, svg, typography, circos

I have the following [Circos](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/dev/circos) diagram, which I rendered as an SVG file and then converted to PNG, for the purposes of illustration:

[image: Circos diagram]

The text labels that circle the outer rim are oriented correctly from 12 o'clock to 9 o'clock, oriented outwards, away from the grey arcs.

Between 9 and 12, the text labels are oriented inwards, overlapping the grey arc. This is not expected.

Here's a close-up, to clarify the issue:

[image]

If I output a PNG from Circos, instead of SVG, the labels are drawn correctly, but then I lose the ability to mark up the vector-formatted SVG figure in Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape. So I need the SVG output.

Here's a snippet of the `circos.conf` file relevant to the addition of the labels:

```
<image>
dir = /tmp
file = circos.png
png = yes
radius = 3000p
background = white
angle_offset = -176
</image>

...

<plots>
<plot>
type                           = text
color                          = black
file                           = factorList.txt
r0                             = 1r
r1                             = 1r+200p
label_size                     = 12p
label_font                     = condensedbold
padding                        = 0p
rpadding                       = 0p
label_snuggle                  = yes
max_snuggle_distance           = 1r
snuggle_sampling               = 2
snuggle_tolerance              = 0.25r
snuggle_link_overlap_test      = yes 
snuggle_link_overlap_tolerance = 2p
snuggle_refine                 = yes
</plot>
</plots>
```

I'm not sure what other options I can apply to try to resolve this. My question is: What should I try in this or another configuration file, which fixes the SVG output? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Give enough information so that one can reproduce the problem on one’s own system. Point to some input data and tell how you invoke the program on the command line.

Comment: Instead of 'fixing' circos to output SVG properly, is it an option to post-process the SVG to find and rotate the incorrectly-rotated items?

Comment: @daxim: Thanks for offering to help, but as there are a number of configuration and data files involved, this question is probably easier to answer by people who have some familiarity with Circos.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this option:

```
label_rotate = no
```

And I think the layout above caused by the snuggle option ,and also check your conf file and be sure all the "r0" and "r1" of plot(type=text) are bigger than 1r .

[Here is the circos lessonss example](http://circos.ca/tutorials/lessons/2d_tracks/text_labels1/lesson)

Comment: The better way to solve it is joining the circos mail list groups.google.com/group/circos-data-visualization .There Martin and circos users will help you directly .